# C# virtual methods

Tags: c#, c++, oop, inheritance, virtual

In C++ I was able to do this

```
class App
{
public:
    virtual void OnMouseMove(etc);
    void FunctionThatDoesStuff();
};

void App::FunctionThatDoesStuff()
{
    // Engine stuff here
    OnMouseMove(etc);
}

class ProjectName : public App
{
public:
    void OnMouseMove(etc);
};

void ProjectName::OnMouseMove(etc)
{
    // User stuff here
}
```

Then when OnMouseMove was called from FunctionThatDoesStuff in App it would be overrode and it would call ProjectName.OnMouseMove instead. But in C# I couldn't do this. This was my first attempt.

```
public class App
{
    protected void MouseMove()
    {
        // Engine code here
        OnMouseMove(etc);
    }

    protected virtual void OnMouseMove(etc)
    {
        // Do Nothing
    }
}

public class ProjectName : App
{
    protected override void OnMouseMove(etc)
    {
        // User code here
    }
}
```

I tried using delegates since they were just functions that aren't implemented. This did not work though. How could I achieve the equivalent in C#? I imagine I could work around it and use events. But is there a more similar way to do this.

Comment: You call `OnMouseMove` from `App` and it calls it's on implementation? What exactly does *could work around it* mean?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thanks. I made the edit to the question.

Comment: Have you created an instance of `App` or `ProjectName`. Show the code how you used it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you are talking about abstract methods or classes:

```
public abstract class App
{
    protected void MouseMove()
    {
        // Engine code here
    }

    protected abstract void OnMouseMove(object etc);
}

public class ProjectName : App
{
    protected override void OnMouseMove(object etc)
    {
        // User code here
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have the default implementation of: `MouseMove`, in `App` Class.

```
public class App
{
    protected void MouseMove()
    {
        // Engine code here
    }

    protected virtual void OnMouseMove(object etc)
   {

   // Default implementation here
    Console.WriteLine('A');

   }
}
```

Then you have the Second class `ProjectName` with another implementation

```
public class ProjectName : App
{
    protected override void OnMouseMove(etc)
    {
        // Overrride implementation

         Console.WriteLine('B')
    }
}
```

Then when you have Object of type: `App` it will print A
And when you have Object of type: 'ProjectName' it will print B

```
    var app = new App();

    var project = new ProjectName();

    app.OnMouseMove();
// Will Print A

    project.OnMouseMove();
// Will Print B
```

Comment: It's possible you missed the edit. MouseMove calls OnMouseMove so that engine code can be implemented without the user seeing it in their own implementation of OnMouseMove.

Comment: Yes, in that case you will have to use abstract method as mentioned in accepted answer.